# Procedure in VHDL never returns the value

Tags: vhdl, procedure

I have a procedure which is never return the value.

```
procedure gen_start_impulse (
    signal rising_signal        : out std_logic;                             
    signal carier_clk           : in std_logic;
    constant duration           : in integer)    is                         
variable clk_counter    : integer := 0;
begin 
    if (rising_edge(carier_clk)) then
        if (clk_counter = duration) then
            rising_signal <= '0';
            clk_counter := 0;
        else
            rising_signal <= '1';
            clk_counter := clk_counter + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end gen_start_impulse;
```

I am call it here

```
process (start)
begin
    if (start = '1') then
        gen_start_impulse(start_impulse, clk, 1);           
    end if;
end process;
```

In testbench start_impulse is uninitialized.

[Result of testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz1cY.png)

I don`t understand why in the waveform start_impulse is uninitialized.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: VHDL procedures don't return a value. It is one of their differences with functions.

Comment: I don`t understand why in the waveform start_impulse is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on Stackoverflow. Your question is interesting but it does not really contain enough information to receive a complete answer (a quick look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section could probably be help you improving it, if you wish).

Anyway, let's try to guess. Your process resumes each time `start` changes and, thanks to your `if` statement, it calls your `gen_start_impulse` procedure only if the new value of `start` is `'1'`. So, just to clarify things, we could probably flatten your model and rewrite your process like this:

```
process (start)
    variable clk_counter: integer := 0;
    constant duration: integer := 1;
begin
    if (start = '1') then
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (clk_counter = duration) then
                start_impulse <= '0';
                clk_counter := 0;
            else
                start_impulse <= '1';
                clk_counter := clk_counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

**Important note**: this is not strictly equivalent to your initial code because in your code the `clk_counter` variable is re-initialized each time your `gen_start_impulse` procedure is called while here it keeps its previous value.

Now, what do you think will happen if `start` is synchronous? That is, if it changes always just after a rising edge of `clk`? Simple: the condition of the:

```
if (rising_edge(clk)) then
```

statement is always false and your signal assignments to `start_impulse` are never executed. This is because `start` and `clk` never change simultaneously. There is always at least one simulation step (a "*delta-cycle*") between them.

If you design a synchronous system wait or check for rising edges of your clock and then test the other signals, not the opposite. Example:

```
procedure gen_start_impulse (
    signal rising_signal        : out std_logic;                             
    signal starter              : in std_logic;
    constant duration           : in integer)    is                         
    variable clk_counter    : integer := 0;
begin 
    if (starter = '1') then
        if (clk_counter = duration) then
            rising_signal <= '0';
            clk_counter := 0;
        else
            rising_signal <= '1';
            clk_counter := clk_counter + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end gen_start_impulse;
...
process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        gen_start_impulse(start_impulse, start, 1);           
    end if;
end process;
```

**Important note**: because of the `clk_counter` variable is re-initialized each time `gen_start_impulse` procedure is called (see previous note), this will not work as you expect. If you want this to work you will need to rework it a bit, either by completely removing the procedure (why do you need it, by the way?) and using only one synchronous process, or by adding a fourth `inout` parameter to your procedure for the `clk_counter` variable ans declaring it as a process variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, but implementation still does not works.  start_impulse is always '1'

Comment: Oh, what I have shown you was not a working solution, it was just an illustration of what I meant with "_design a synchronous system_". There are several other reasons why it still doesn't work. For instance local variables in a procedure (e.g. `clk_counter`) are re-initialized each time you call the procedure (local variables of processes behave differently). But as you don't show a MCVE we cannot find all the reasons. You should really consider visiting the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and improving your question with a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).